No internet access with IPv6 prefix delegation to vlan with systemd-networkd
I have a router that gets a /48 prefix from my ISP, and had prefix delegation enabled.
I run a (debain)server on the router's main network.
I've set up a vlan for my IoT devices on my server, for ipv4 I have set up a NAT to connect the device on the vlan to the internet.
I've managed to configure systemd-networkd to request a prefix from the router and apply it on the iot vlan interface. Systemd-networkd also serves as router advertisement for the clients on the vlan. When connecting a device to the iot-vlan it receives a ipv6 address within the prefix.
So far so good.
However, the addresses within the prefix are not routed to the internet.
I seem to be missing the part where the server 'knows' that traffic from the prefix :C001: needs to be forwarded to the router (over eth0).
Pinging google.com from the main interface of my server:
# ping6 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e -I eth0
PING 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e(2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e) from 2a02:a46e:53ea:0:54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d eth0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=7.13 ms


Pinging from the iot-vlan interface:
# ping6 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e -I iot 
PING 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e(2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e) from 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d iot: 56 data bytes
From 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable


edit: Pinging from the address of the iot interface works (tnx @u1686_grawity)
$ ping6 google.com -I "2a02:a46e:53ea:c000:54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d"
PING google.com(ams17s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:810::200e)) from 2a02:a46e:53ea:c000:54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d : 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ams17s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:810::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=7.64 ms

Pinging from a device in the iot-vlan does not work.
$ ping6 google.com
PING google.com (2a00:1450:400e:803::200e) 56 data bytes
--- google.com ping statistics ---
236 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 240617ms

ip address of device on iot-vlan:
$ ip -6 addr show dev wlp1s0
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet6 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:dc81:6cfc:2115:899/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3576sec preferred_lft 1776sec
    inet6 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:4f32:ea73:f336:3907/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3576sec preferred_lft 1776sec
    inet6 fe80::aff0:9c03:3ce:7601/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

route of device on iot-vlan
$ ip -6 route
2a02:a46e:53ea:c001::/64 dev wlp1s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth0ad8518 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth998c5e2 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::54ce:59ff:fec6:b62d dev wlp1s0 proto ra metric 20600 pref medium

The systemd .network file for the vlan-interface:
[Match]
Name=iot
Type=vlan

[Network]
DHCPPrefixDelegation=yes
IPv6DuplicateAddressDetection=1
IPv6SendRA=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[Address]
Address=192.168.100.1/24

[DHCPPrefixDelegation]
UplinkInterface=:auto
SubnetId=1
Announce=yes

#[Route]       
#Gateway=::
#Table=local
#This does not seem to do anything

Edit:
tcpdump shows my ping request entering the server in interface iot:
#tcpdump -eni iot ip6
15:49:12.290030 c0:a5:e8:46:79:31 > 56:ce:59:c6:b6:2d, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:dc81:6cfc:2115:899 > 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e: ICMP6, echo request, id 30134, seq 1, length 64

but not being forwarded to eth0 (only the same packet WITH vlan tag):
#tcpdump -eni eth0 ip6
15:50:55.083174 c0:a5:e8:46:79:31 > 56:ce:59:c6:b6:2d, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 122: vlan 2, p 0, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), 2a02:a46e:53ea:c001:dc81:6cfc:2115:899 > 2a00:1450:400e:80f::200e: ICMP6, echo request, id 30653, seq 1, length 64


@u1686_grawity When I ping from a remote host I have the same result. When I am on a network with the :0: prefix I can reach the internet, when on :C001: I cannot.
I did just check with wireshark, when I ping from a :C001: host, the packets /are/ forwarded to eth0


I seem to be missing the part where the server 'knows' that traffic from the prefix :C001: needs to be forwarded to the router (over eth0).

It doesn't need to know that. Most routing is not specific by source address, so because the host already has a general "::/0 via router dev eth0" route (i.e. your default route), that route covers both the traffic from the host itself and the traffic from any other prefix that happens to arrive at the host.
While source-specific routes do exist in IPv6, they are very much an exception, not the rule. (If you had one, you'd see "::/0 from xxx:/64 via..." in your routing table.)

Pinging from the iot-vlan interface:

The problem is that the address being pinged is not reachable through that interface. The command did literally what you describe – it didn't simply bind to the IP address of this interface; it actually tried to send packets through this interface as well.
If you're used to tools where -I simply takes the address of the specified interface, that's one area where different programs implement a similar option differently, with opposite results.
Instead, you need to specify just the address of iot-vlan as the -I parameter.

Tnx, this fixes my understanding a little bit. It seems the prefix is usable on the server, but not on actual devices on the network

That might be a firewall issue or something else, depending on what tcpdump etc. reveal. Does a tcpdump -eni iot-vlan ip6 show packets entering the router, and does another tcpdump on its eth0 show the same packets leaving?

I've added the tcpdump results to the original question

My firewall blocked ipv6 forwarding by default.
Enabling forwarding from iot to eth0 and vice versa solved my issues.
